# Using rsync to backup system data gives "No such file"

Tags: shell, rsync, backup

I'm trying to backup my entire system directory using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /

BACKUP_LOCATION=/media/data/backup/system-backup/

echo Backing up system data to $BACKUP_LOCATION, excluding home directories
sudo rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/home/*", "/swap.img", "/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / $BACKUP_LOCATION
```

When running this, I'm getting the following error:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/swap.img," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

As far as I understand, the exclude paths are relative to the source directory, being /, therefore e.g. /home/* should resolve to /home/* on the real file system. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I prefer to just backup /home. Files in /etc that are edited are copied into /home folder & I export list of installed apps. Then I can just totally reinstall Ubuntu & restore config  easily. And easier for me to have a separate exclude file. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Comment: Thanks for that link. I'm also doing a regular /home only backup, but wanted to do a complete system one once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing the command

```
sudo rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/home/*", "/swap.img", "/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / $BACKUP_LOCATION
```

shells which support brace expansion will only perform it on a word if it contains a correctly-formed brace expression. You can test how the command is interpreted by executing, for example:

```
 bash -xc 'rsync -aAXvn --exclude={"/home", "/swap.img", "/dev"} / /media/data/backup/system-backup/' 2>&1 | grep ^\+
```

the result is

```
+ rsync -aAXvn '--exclude={/home,' /swap.img, '/dev}' / /media/data/backup/system-backup/
```

in other words, the shell performs word splitting, which converts `--exclude={"/home", "/swap.img", "/dev"}` into three arguments: `--exclude={/home,` (which isn't a correctly-formed brace expression, as it doesn't have a closing brace), `/swap.img,` (including the comma), and `/dev}`.

If instead the command

```
bash -xc 'rsync -aAXvn --exclude={"/home","/swap.img","/dev"} / /media/data/backup/system-backup/' 2>&1 | grep ^\+
```

is executed, we see the correct brace expansion into three separate `--exclude` arguments:

```
+ rsync -aAXvn --exclude=/home --exclude=/swap.img --exclude=/dev / /media/data/backup/system-backup/
```

Comment: In summary, do not put spaces between components of a brace expansion

Comment: Unless spaces are desired, in which case they should be protected.

Comment: They wouldn't be spaces _between components_ then, though.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue of semantics, as English is not my native language, but to have spaces *at all* as part of the brace expression they need to be protected.

Comment: `{"two words",three\ words\ here}` is a valid expansion, but `{"two words", alone}` is not. I think we mean the same thing - the first one contains spaces that need to be protected within each component but the second one has a space after the comma that breaks the `{a,b,c}` expansion syntax

Comment: That is correct.